# Salesforce monorail org when opened using selenium automation shows "Not Secure" Site

Tags: chrome, test-automation, selenium, webdriver

The salesforce Spring'24 monorail org when logged through browser works fine. But, if opened via selenium webDriver connection shows "Not Secure" message in the URL.
For all other other orgs be it PreRelease/Production/Sandbox orgs, we did not encounter this issue. What could be the possible reason for this?

Certificate used for monorail org: [image]

For other sandbox orgs via automation:

[image]

Chrome Driver used : chrome-driver 120.0.6099.109
Chrome Browser : 120.0.6099.109 (Official Build) (x86_64)